# Presto equivalent of CONCAT_WS

Tags: sql, presto, string-concatenation

I'm looking for a function in Presto to concat two columns with a separator like underline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your are looking here for the `array_join` function, see [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html).

> **array_join(x, delimiter, null_replacement)** → varchar
>
> *Concatenates the elements of the given array using the*
> *delimiter and an optional string to replace nulls.*

**Example:**
*columns are c1,c2  you can add more of course:*

```
WITH  demo_table (c1,c2) AS 
    (SELECT * FROM  (VALUES  (1,2),(3,4),(5,null),(7,8) ))
SELECT array_join(array[c1,c2], '_', 'NA')
FROM demo_table
```

***Results will be:***
*1_2

3_4

5_NA

7_8*

Comment: One caveat is that ARRAY elements must be all same type. So if you want to contact strings and numbers together, you'll need to CAST numbers into varchar for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

To handle:

```
select concat_ws(',', col1, col2)
```

You can use:

```
select substr( concat(case when col1 is not null then ',' || col1 else '' end,
                      case when col2 is not null then ',' || col2 else '' end

                     ),
                2
             )
```

This concatenates the non-NULL values into a string.  The resulting string will start with a comma.  The `substr()` removes the first character.

Comment: presto doesn't support logical operators on strings

Comment: @MTT . . . I fixed the concat operator -- and `+` is not a *logical* operator, it is an *arithmetic* operator.

Answer (score 3):

This has been added to PrestoSQL (now Trino) a couple of releases back: https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html

```
concat_ws(string0, string1, ..., stringN) → varchar#
Returns the concatenation of string1, string2, ..., stringN using string0 as a separator. If string0 is null, then the return value is null. Any null values provided in the arguments after the separator are skipped.

concat_ws(string0, array(varchar)) → varchar
Returns the concatenation of elements in the array using string0 as a separator. If string0 is null, then the return value is null. Any null values in the array are skipped.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(col1, ',', col2)
```

Comment: . . This answer is not correct.  It does not handle `NULL` values correctly.